# Ubuntu missing files and folders

Tags: 15.04, directory

[image: Error Message Image]

When trying to access folders like Documents,Downloads etc in Ubuntu 15.04 an error message is shown that the file doesn't exist.

" Unable to find the requested file. Please check the spelling and try again.
Unhandled error message: Error when getting information for file '/home/nikhil/Music': No such file or directory "

What should I do to get back these folders?

Comment: There is probably something wrong with your file `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks`.  Please edit your question and add the contents of this file.

Comment: Where is this file located?

Comment: `~` denotes the current user's home directory. So in your case it would be `/home/nikhil/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks`.

Comment: Shows no such file or directory.

Comment: In terminal if I type ls there is no folder or files.

Comment: Do you have  a file `.config/user-dirs.dirs`? That should contain links for all  your Documents, Downloads, etc. folders.

Comment: No. That file is not there.

Comment: There is no folders inside home.

Comment: if there is nothing listed when you do `ls -l /home` from the command line, you'll need to restore from backup.